# sql - union tables with same prefix

Tags: sql, sql-server, union, prefix

I have a set of tables with **same prefix** and **same structure**. All I need is to "combine" them as one.

```
use thisdb
declare @maxrow int, @result nvarchar(4000), @tempname nvarchar(20)
set @maxrow = (select count(*) from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'dbo' and table_name like N'AAbc%')
set @result = ''
set @tempname = 'mytemp'
select @result = @result + case when [row] = 1 then replace([name],'from',concat('into ##',@tempname, ' from')) when [row] = @maxrow then replace([name],'union all','') else [name] end + ' ' 
from 
(select ['table_name,'] union all') as [name], row_number() over(order by table_name asc) as [Row]
from information_schema.tables
where table_schema = 'dbo' and table_name like N'AAbc%') x
execute sp_executesql @result
```

Basically I retrieve tables with certain pattern from `information_schema.tables`, then get rid of the last `union all`.

Above method works for 20-30 tables, as the `@result` won't exceed the limit for `nvarchar`. But I'm curious how to get this job done if number of tables N is very large? Or there's better way to deal with this problem?

Comment: Hi, please add in your tag list, your DBMS

Comment: I think the real question is why you would want to do this, especially for more than 30 tables

Comment: Create a view with union of that tables (script can be generated in excel, for example) and use single object to access with plain SQL, not dynamic

Comment: @JoeTaras Microsoft SQL Server 2014

Comment: @HoneyBadger I need to do some analysis on those tables. Say, do calculation then segmentation based on calculated results.The table is generated on a monthly basis. If I incorporate tables of consecutive 4 years, it will be 48 tables.

Comment: *"I have a set of tables with same prefix and same structure."* This sounds like a design flaw, if you have 30 tables with the same design, why are they not *one* (partitioned) table?

Comment: *"Above method works for 20-30 tables, as the `@result` won't exceed the limit for `nvarchar`"* An `nvarchar` can have up to 1 billion~ characters (2GB of text), if you're reaching the limit, you have *far* more than 30 tables.

Comment: @Larnu Why the maximum I can set for ```@result``` is only 4000? Otherwise it pops up error. The tables are provided by third party and I can't ask them to change.

Comment: You aren't defined the value as a `MAX`. SQL Server won't implicitly convert a non-`MAX` data type to a `MAX` one.

Comment: @Lovnlust `varchar(4000)` is definitely [cannot have more than](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) 4000 bytes, use `varchar(MAX)`. But the real question is why do you generate so much tables instead of single partitioned table. What if on some day the table will need and update in the structure and have some additional columns? Your approach will fail. Or I'll wait for questions like *How to alter 72 tables by name pattern with the same column*.

Comment: You could just use a temp table with an identity auto-inc ID field and add each command to be executed into each field, then just iterate through the list executing the sql. It is of course less efficient than generating a single select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should suffice. "Union all" replaced with "Go".

```
declare @script nvarchar(max)

set @script = (
SELECT STUFF(( SELECT  'insert #MyTable(sharedColName1, SharedColName2) select sharedColName1, SharedColName2 from ' + Table_Name + ' Go '
                FROM    ( SELECT DISTINCT
                                    Table_Name
                          FROM      INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables
                          where table_Name Like '<prefix_for_tables_with_identical_names>%'
                        ) x
              FOR
                XML PATH('')
              ), 1, 0, '') A
              )
sp_executeSql @script
```